# Accessing object element by index

Tags: php, object, ebay-api, arrayaccess, ebay-sdk

I'm using eBay API which returns:

```
DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType Object
(
    [data:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 60
        )

    [position:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType:private] => 0
    [class:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType:private] => DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType
    [property:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType:private] => Value
    [expectedType:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType:private] => string
)
```

... and if I try to access it like so:

```
echo $ItemSpecific->Value->{0};
```

... I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType::$0 in ...

Comment: It's an array in an object, access it as that - `$ItemSpecific->Value[0];` :-)

Comment: `Array
        (
            [0] => 60
        )` this is an array not a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType`](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php/blob/9d490d7c0838eb0c3ccb9ac80e2645c05d7f9612/src/Types/RepeatableType.php) implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface, you can access the items of the private `$data` array as follows:

```
foreach ($ItemSpecific as $item) {
  var_dump($item);
}
```

or by index: `$ItemSpecific[0]`. But it's more likely that you need to iterate the object in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I use to run into this same issue.  The problem is that the information you want to parse out appears to be a private property of an object.  Private properties of an object are restricted to the object.  Standard practice of getting a private property to call a public function with in the object to output the value.  It's likely that such a function does not exist and therefore you cannot parse the information.

These rules, however, will only apply with in the realm of PHP.  If you change this information into a static value, these rules will no longer apply.

```
<?php
function parse($obj, $start="[", $end = "]"){
    $string = json_encode($obj);
    $s = strpos($string, $start) + 1;
    $e = strpos($string, $end);
    $diff = $e - $s;
    return substr($string, $s, $diff);
}

  echo parse($ItemSpecific->Value);
```

Now I do not have a sample of your exact API result so you might have to change the parameters a bit, but this general idea should solve your problem.